# Multiple containers of docker image using same volumes in docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a python project which I have converted to a docker image. I need to run 2 containers of this docker image with different configs and different volumes. So I have put everything in docker compose file. Below is the file content:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
    s1:
        image: testdockerimg:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/s1config.json:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/config.json
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 2g

    s2:
        image: testdockerimg:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/s2config.json:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/config.json
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 2g
```

As you can see that I am starting two containers i.e. `s1` `s2` of docker image `testdockerimg`. Both of them has same volume but difference is I am giving `s1config.json` as `config.json` to s1 container and `s2config.json` as `config.json` to s2 container.  This `config.json` has different configuration for different containers and is read by python file in docker to perform all the logic.

Now as per my understanding, both of these containers will have their own separate volumes, which means they are acting as two different machines having the volumes as mentioned above. But looks like both of the containers are using the 1 shared volume instead of having 2 separate volumes. I can confirm this as python code inside the docker pushes all the data to iot hub portal and I can see that `s1` has same data  as `s2`. I can also confirm this looking at the log file as their are 2 entries for each log in file.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong. Does volumes across each containers remains same or its different. I do not want to create another docker image and would like to simply run another container having different config and volume so that all the data of the container is separate from other containers. Please help. Thanks

Comment: The second line of both `volumes:` blocks mounts the same host directory into each container, so they're sharing storage.

Comment: @DavidMaze How come they are sharing storage. These two containers are running seprately so they should have their own volume instead of shared.

Comment: @DavidMaze Does this also means that I cannot run multiple container for same image

Comment: You've set both containers to use the same host directory `/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI`.  If you use `volumes:` like this Docker does exactly what you ask it to; it doesn't allocate extra storage or somehow virtualize the contents of the host directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have 1 docker image for which I want to run 2 containers. Is there anyway I can separate these volumes because I dont want to create multiple docker images.?